# Saving conditions whether a user has done something in MongoDB: which field type should I use?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

So I have this scenario where I want to save a condition whether if a user "has joined the website onboarding tour". So the question I want to ask is not how to save the field to MongoDB, but rather what field type should I use for it?

I want it to be reusable for another certain condition such as "has joined a campaign A", or "has visited special page B". Now I have 3 cases that you can look:

Case 1: Just a single boolean field for every case: One field for one condition, such as `hasJoinedNewOnboarding: true` or `hasJoinedCampaignA: false`. All I need to do is search by `key: true`.

Case 2: Use an array: One array for many conditions, such as `['hasJoinedNewOnboarding','hasJoinedCampaignA']`. Let's say the field name is `meta_data`. All I need to do is search using $elemMatch like `{ meta_data: { $elemMatch: { 'hasJoinedNewOnboarding' } } }`

Case 3: Use an object: One object for many conditions, such as Case 2: Use an array: One array for many conditions, such as `{ hasJoinedNewOnboarding: true, hasJoinedCampaignA: false }`. Let's say the field name is `meta_data`. All I need to do is search it like `{ 'meta_data.hasJoinedNewOnboarding': true }`

With that said, which one do you think is the best way to store the conditions in the database? Or do you have something in mind that is better than these 3 cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much difference when you want to query your data, it will always be either:

```
db.col.find({hasJoinedNewOnboarding: true})
```

or for the second approach:

```
db.col.find({arrayName: "hasJoinedNewOnboarding"})
```

Both ways are easy however I would recommend storing such events in an array because it's easier to aggregate the data when you don't need to refer to multiple key names in MongoDB,

For example, if you have a document like:

```
{
    events: [
        "hasJoinedNewOnboarding",
        "hasJoinedCampaignA"
    ]
}
```

You can dynamically count how many users have done something by running following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$events"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$events",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9GPimFvKNh2)

Alternatively if you decide to use first or third approach the name of the event is represented by the name of the key in MongoDB's document so you can still easily count single event occurances but if you want to group all events dynamically you need to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) operator which becomes more cumbersome.

So the recommended approach would be to keep them as an array of strings or an array of objects like:

```
{ events: [ { eventType: "NewOnboarding", date: ... } ] }
```

Comment: Ah, never thought of saving the done date. Actually, I like the approach of array of objects. Tried with this schema where I only search for the Event name (https://mongoplayground.net/p/lj5EXn9KqdG), and it works! Thanks for the insight :)